# Access private method in an overriden method called from the base class constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, overriding, private-members

Consider the following code:

```js
class MyBase {
  constructor(b) {
    this.myOverrideMethod(b);
  }
  myOverrideMethod(b) {}
}
class MyClass extends MyBase {
  constructor(b) {
    super(b);
  }
  myOverrideMethod(b) {
    if (b) {
      this.mySpecificMethod();
    } else {
      this.#myPrivateMethod();
    }
  }
  mySpecificMethod() {
    console.log('mySpecificMethod');
  }
  #myPrivateMethod = () => {
    console.log('#myPrivateMethod');
  };
}
new MyClass(true);  // <-- "mySpecificMethod"
new MyClass(false); // <-- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member #myPrivateMethod 
                    //     from an object whose class did not declare it
```

The overridden method of `myOverrideMethod()` is called in the constructor of the "base" class. Since `this` points to an instance of `MyClass`, the overrided method in the derived class is invoked correctly. The regular method of `mySpecificMethod()` gets called successfully, while invoking the private field of `#myPrivateMethod()` throws the following "TypeError":

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member `#myPrivateMethod` from an object whose class did not declare it*

The error message does not convey the issue as being *a private field access violation*, but rather evokes the `this` does not yet reference an instance of `MyClass` but still references an instance of `MyBase`! However, why is that and how to successfully invoke the private method of `#myPrivateMethod()`?

Comment: Never call overrideable methods from the constructor, and don't use class fields for methods.

Answer (score 5):

This is only an issue when trying to call the private method during the constructor. I think it's because the child class hasn't yet been fully constructed while in the parent's constructor, so the private method isn't available yet.

See the example below where I call `this.myOverrideMethod()` from an ordinary method, and the call is allowed.

```js
class MyBase {
  constructor() {
  }
  doit(b) {
    this.myOverrideMethod(b);
  }
  myOverrideMethod(b) {}
}
class MyClass extends MyBase {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  myOverrideMethod(b) {
    if (b) {
      this.mySpecificMethod();
    } else {
      this.#myPrivateMethod();
    }
  }
  mySpecificMethod() {
    console.log('mySpecificMethod');
  }
  #myPrivateMethod = () => {
    console.log('#myPrivateMethod');
  };
}
new MyClass().doit(true);
new MyClass().doit(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's right, the issue is with the "constructor" only; It's weird that while the _"child class hasn't yet been fully constructed"_ but still it can resolve the "regular" methods and not the "private" ones!! Also unfortunately my specific case is a complex hierarchy where the call stack must go through the constructor, and it cannot be done via a proxy method after getting _"fully constructed"_.

Comment: Private methods may be too new for there to be much experience in the nuances.

Comment: @dev2020 It can resolve prototype methods, it cannot resolve instance methods. This has nothing to do with them being private or not.

Comment: Why does it work with `mySpecificMethod`? It's an instance method, isn't it?

Comment: @Barmar No, that's defined on the prototype as well. By "instance method" I mean those that are created on an *own* property of the instance inside the constructor,

Comment: Oh, I see, the private method is defined with `name = func` rather than `func()`

Comment: @Bergi It does resolve the _"private instance fields"_, but only after being "fully constructed" (as Barmar has pointed-out in this answer). As I've stated in the original post, it's not an out-of-scope access violation error; but rather, having the flow being in the base class constructor, the section corresponding to the derived class instance construction has not been reached-out yet and thus the error, while apparently the "prototypal methods" have already been processed ahead of getting into the class inheritance hierarchy for construction!!

Comment: @dev2020 Yes, that's what I said. It wouldn't work with `mySpecificMethod`  either if that was defined using class field syntax as well.

Comment: There are no such official terms "fully" / "not fully" constructed. This is the bug in javascript engine and should be reported to the developers.